# How to find and replace with notepad++ for those may have many space

Tags: notepad++

```
CREATE VIEW
CREATE  VIEW
CREATE   VIEW

ALTER VIEW
```

every time i have to press more space to find matching the whole word

however i do not know how many space may be between CREATE and VIEW

Comment: you can solve the problem with regex

Comment: what are you trying to do..do you want to replace multiple space into single space..and what have you tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open up the "Replace" dialogue: `Ctrl+H` or `Search > Replace`.
2. Click the "Regular Expression" setting at the lower left.
3. Use these settings:

   Find what: "`+`" (space followed by '+'; this will find any occurrence of at least one space)

   Replace with: "" (single space; this will insert a single space in all of the above environments)
4. Click "Replace All".

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this with a regular expression. In the find and replace dialog:

> Find what: CREATE +VIEW
>
> Replace with: CREATE VIEW

This will normalise the spaces on where there are multiple spaces between a "CREATE" and a "VIEW"

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a regular expression within Notepad++ to do this search and replace.